# How to get filtered value from kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, php, filter, kendo-grid

My question is how can I fetch filtered value to use it for further operation? and also how can I use footertemplate value? I searched at many forums and telerik method option also but not getting what i want. Please help me if anyone know answer

Thanks!

I tried this:

```
var dataSource =  $("#report").data("kendoGrid").dataSource; 

 var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
     data: dataSource.data(), 
     filter: dataSource.filter() 
 }); 

filteredDataSource.read();

var data = filteredDataSource.view();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [fiddle](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/oYiN) for you to check out. It appears that your code does indeed return the filtered data on clicking "Run" below the grid and looking at the console window. So, it is not clear what you are having trouble with. Do you have any browser console errors?